# python: dynamically adding attributes to a built-in class

Tags: python, attributes, python-3.x, subclass

Why doesn't it work for the built-in classes?

Is using a subclass the best approach to fix it, or will I run into some hidden problems?

```
a = {}
a.p = 1 # raises AttributeError
class B(dict):
  pass
b = B()
b.p = 1 # works
```

EDIT: my original comment that it doesn't work for `b` was incorrect (I made a mistake).

Comment: Short lazy answer: `__slots__`; also `dict` is implemented in C, and you're inheriting it.

Comment: what python version are you using? b.p = 1 works both in 2.7.2 and 3.2

Comment: Terribly sorry, it does work for b. Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: You can make chnages to the built-in classes thenselves-  you have to create subclasses of them.

Comment: There is no need to inherit from `dict`. In fact Python doesn't appreciate inheriting from base classes at all.

Comment: @BasicWolf: Why do you say that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The builtin classes do not have the ability to have arbitrary attributes. This is done for reasons of performance, especially memory usage, you want the built-in classes like `list` and `dict` to be as small as possible so you can have many of them.

Therefore the built-in classes do not have the `__dict__` dictionary that is needed for arbitrary attributes to work.

You can achieve the same for your classes. If they are written in C you simply do not implement the `__dict__` support. If they are written in Python you use [slots](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subclass `dict` you can always use `UserDict` ([here the documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict)).

And it works with what you're trying to do:

```
from collections import UserDict

a = UserDict()
a.p = 10 # works fine
```